# how to navigate to another tab when tapped on button in react native?

Tags: react-native

i am new to react native,
i have an application with tab bar, navigation bar and drawer.

structure looks like:

```
Tab.Navigator
    Tab.Screen
        StackNavigator
            StackScreen
                Screen(A)
    Tab.Screen
        StackNavigator
            StackScreen
                Screen(B)
    Tab.Screen
        StackNavigator
            StackScreen
                Screen(C)
    Tab.Screen
        StackNavigator
            StackScreen
                Screen(D)
Tab.Navigator
```

I am at the screen (C) and when the user taps on the button on screen C, I want to navigate to screen(D).

without resetting the tab bar.

and

```
Stack.Navigator
   Stack.Screen
     Drawer
        Stack.Navigator
           Stack.Screen
             Tab.Navigator
             Screen (X)
             Screen (Y)
             Screen (Z)
```

and another question:
from screen(Z) , how can i navigate it to screen(C)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```js
navigation.jumpTo('StackName',{screen:'ScreenName'})
```

Comment: error: this.props.navigation.jumpTo is not a function

Comment: which navigation version you are using?

Comment: "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.15",
    "@react-navigation/compat": "^5.3.20",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.7.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.9",

Comment: from screen(Z) , how can i navigate it to screen(C)?

Comment: @Matrix Maybe you could try the [`useNavigation`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation) hook in your app.